# The expression of the cyclic submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I found a statement that

> The cyclic submodule $C$ generated by $a$ is $\left\{ ra+na|r\in R;n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$.

I am confused that $rna$ should also be in the submodule but I can not express it useing the element in {$ra+na|r\in R;n\in N$}, could you express it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: In this book the definitioin of the module do not see multiplication identity in Ring as the necessary condition@Stefan

Comment: I deleted the comment red_rose referred to. It was meaningless after related comments were deleted by a moderator - quite needlessly in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $R$ is a nonunital ring (or even a semiring), so that $na$ cannot be rewritten as $ra$ in general. But $rna$ (with $r \in R$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$) can be rewritten as $\left(nr\right)a$, where $nr$ is defined as usual (knowing that $R$ itself is an abelian group or monoid, and thus an element of $R$ can be multiplied by a natural number). Thus, $rna$ can be rewritten as $ra$ with a different $r$.